# Windows Login Script ignore UAC

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-server-2008-r2, uac, group-policy

I have a GPO that will launch a Startup Script for a .exe(Install Shield) silent unattended setup. However the user is currently being prompted to allow program due to UAC. **I want a true unattended setup with out any user interaction.**

Here is the batch: NOTE this setup.exe is being installed from a mapped network shared. Ex `M:/setup.exe.` The script is located in the mapped network share as well.

```
@Echo Off
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\(path)\file.exe (
    REM Do one thing
Echo Program Already Installed
) ELSE (
M:/setup.exe /S /v/qn
Echo Program Being Installed
)
```

There is nothing wrong with the script and it runs, but due to UAC on client computer it ask if user wants to install setup.exe. How can we get around this message without any user interaction and with out disabling UAC for user?

UAC Message I want batch script to ignore!:

[image]

Comment: This is a possible answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/19/how-to-bypass-the-security-warning-unknown-publisher-with-the-checkbox-always-ask-before-opening-this-file.aspx But a security risk?!?

Comment: Other methods. The right suggested one.

Comment: Make the batch file copy the files it needs to somewhere on C:\.

Comment: Few things to consider/try: Use the "Computer" configuration GPs to run it (Startup script instead of Logon script), ensure you're referencing the share by name and not by IP, and ensure that the installer EXE has been "unblocked".